# error: expected ')' before 'CLLocation'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocation

i get this error:

> error: expected ')' before 'CLLocation'

with this code:

```
@protocol MyCLControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location; 
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
@end

@interface MyCLController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyCLControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

the code, I think is well, the problem I think is the library, but I added the framework previously but doesn't work.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you use the "{}" button, it'll wrap your code in very nice formatting, making it EVER so much easier for people to help you with your question. I took care of it for you this time.

Comment: `CLLocation` appears several times in that code.  Which line is it that is giving the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you imported it?

At the top of the file, go:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the answer, in other projects i did not need to impor it, thanks for the answer :D